# Metis (python interface) minimum graph cut wrong result (or usage?)

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, metis

I am trying to do what I though was a simple graph partition using metis. The objective is to minimize graph cut cost with fixed number of k partitions.

I set up a small simple problem with all edges having high weight (don't cut), and only one having low weight (please cut here).

In the example I would expect the only cut is on edge 10 between node 3 and 24 having weight 1.

Metis is returning very bad results with the lowest edge not being cut but cuts all over the place (even if I set contiguos = True). The cutcost also seems to be wrong.

I would like to hear from someone that is more familiar than me with this class of problems

This is the python script I am using:

```
import networkx as nx
import metis

#all edges have high weight, I expect the cut to be coming on edge 10 between node 3 an 24
edges=[(33, 34, 1000), (1, 18, 1000), (1, 17, 1000), (17, 34, 1000), (48, 49, 1000), (18, 48, 1000), (25, 50, 1000), (49, 50, 1000), (24, 25, 1000), (3, 30, 1000), (3, 24, 1), (31, 32, 1000), (30, 31, 1000), (22, 32, 1000), (3, 47, 1000), (46, 47, 1000), (0, 20, 1000), (0, 4, 1000), (4, 29, 1000), (28, 29, 1000), (28, 46, 1000), (20, 21, 1000), (2, 21, 1000), (40, 42, 1000), (2, 40, 1000), (12, 41, 1000), (41, 42, 1000), (13, 14, 1000), (12, 13, 1000), (8, 16, 1000), (8, 14, 1000), (15, 16, 1000), (6, 7, 1000), (6, 15, 1000), (5, 6, 1000), (5, 9, 1000), (10, 11, 1000), (9, 10, 1000), (0, 19, 1000), (36, 44, 1000), (26, 36, 1000), (26, 27, 1000), (4, 27, 1000), (43, 45, 1000), (44, 45, 1000), (55, 56, 1000), (37, 55, 1000), (37, 38, 1000), (38, 43, 1000), (35, 56, 1000), (37, 39, 1000), (51, 52, 1000), (39, 52, 1000), (53, 54, 1000), (1, 53, 1000), (23, 54, 1000)]

ne = len(edges)

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)

print(G.number_of_edges())
print(G.number_of_nodes())

# Add node weights to graph
for i in range(G.number_of_nodes()):
    G.nodes[i]['node_value'] = 1

 
# tell METIS which node attribute to use for 
G.graph['node_weight_attr'] = 'node_value' 
G.graph['edge_weight_attr']='weight' 


# Check graph attributes for weight/size labels
edgew = G.graph.get('edge_weight_attr', None)
nodew = G.graph.get('node_weight_attr', [])
nodesz = G.graph.get('node_size_attr', None)


# Get at MOST two partitions from METIS
(cutcost, parts) = metis.part_graph(G, nparts = 2, objtype="cut") 

#parts [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
#cutcost 1001 


#???????????????????????????????????

print(parts)

# Assuming you have PyDot installed, produce a DOT description of the graph:
colors = ['red', 'blue']
for i, part in enumerate(parts):
    G.nodes[i]['color'] = colors[part]
nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(G, 'example.dot')
```

and here the graphiz picture:

[image]

Comment: I would expect METIS to be able to bisect a tree (?) with only one cut edge, though depending on the coarsening algorithm, not necessarily the cheapest edge since it's hard to find by greedily improving the partition. Not sure what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You may push code

```
G.graph['edge_weight_attr'] = 'weight'
```

before pass the graph into the function